# Should I use logistic mixed effects? How?

Tags: logistic, spss, matlab, mixed-model, effects

I've run an experiment in which different subjects had to make a number of decisions, which are stored in the dependent boolean variable Y (0 or 1). I have multiple independed variables which may influence the outcome, namely an ordinal variable containing integers running from -4 to 4 (o1), two nominal variables which may have three values (n1 and n2) and the ID number of the test subject (ID), which is of course nominal.

Now the obvious question is how Y depends on o1, n1 and n2. I figured that because Y is a boolean, you want to make a logistic regression model to calculate the chance of the outcome being 1. Because both nominal and ordinal independend variables are used you would use multinomial logistic regression. (Right?)

Someone in my lab suggested to use a mixed effects model, because the intercept might vary per subject. He had me look up linear mixed effects. But would it not make more sense to use a logistic mixed effects?

Then, my next question is: how can I make this model using software? I plan to use either SPSS or Matlab/octave.

I apologise if this is a duplicate question, but an internet search did not answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your colleague is right, using a mixed model will be the most appropriate.
In Matlab 2013b above you can apply linear mixed model if you have Statistics toolbox
http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/linear-mixed-effects-models.html

And in your case you might want to consider using a Generalised linear mixed model, which is available from Matlab 2014b onward
http://ch.mathworks.com/help/stats/generalized-linear-mixed-effects-models.html

If you dont have these version of Matlab, you can also do the linear mixed model by hand using the nlmefit function.

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't want multinomial logistic. The type of regression you need depends on the dependent variable. Since your dependent variable is dichotomous, normal logistic is right.

Second. you do need a multilevel model/mixed model since your data is not independent (your colleague is right).

The third part of your question is off topic here, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you! And is it true that I should count n1 and n2 as fixed effects (o1 is definitely a fixed effect) and subject ID number as a random effect?

Comment: That sounds right to me